# Unable to run a service command via cron

Tags: service, cron

```
service service_name start
```

When i tried running this from cmd line, it works. But when i try to schedule it via cron, i get an error saying

> /bin/sh: service: command not found

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`sbin` is not in the path when run via cron. Specify the full path to `service`. This is probably either `/sbin/service` or `/usr/sbin/service`. You can find the path on your system by running `which service`.

Comment: Splendid! This started happening when I updated Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

Comment: while trying to up-vote this message it looks like I already voted it 5 years ago :)