# One system command from Python not working when executed with cron

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm facing a strange problem. I have a Python script that includes the following line

```
  subprocess.call("ifconfig ens3 inet6 add " + str(address) + "/64", shell=True)
```

It assigns a ip to the OS in a loop. The problem I'm facing is that the IPs get assigned if I manually run it, but the IPs don't get assigned when I run it with cron at reboot. I do know the script does run at boot because I send the results to a log. But when I check with `ip -6 addr` the IPs are not assigned if the script ran with cron. But they are assigned if I run it myself.

Comment: Cron sometimes doesn't have a `$PATH` variable, and thus cannot find the location of `ifconfig`. Have you tried replacing it with `/sbin/ifconfig` (or wherever `ifconfig` may be)?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: It worked. You can write it in the answer and I will accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run a service command via cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127433/unable-to-run-a-service-command-via-cron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron sometimes doesn't have a `$PATH` variable set, and thus cannot find the location of `ifconfig`. Replace it with `/sbin/ifconfig` (or wherever `ifconfig` may be).

Comment: Technically, I believe `cron`, and pretty much every other process on a system, with the exception maybe of `init` and some other early boot things, will have a `PATH` variable available to it. It certainly does on my system, when I look at `/proc/<pid>/environ`. It's more correct to say that the contents of that `PATH` variable are often not what a user expects.