# Troubleshooting Cron with Curl on Pushgateway (Prometheus)

Tags: bash, curl, cron, debian, prometheus

I'm testing Pushgateway along Prometheus, pushing simple data about my VMs' services every minute with a bash script and curl, triggered by crontab.

I have two bash scripts.
The first one, `cpu_usage.sh`, parse and send data about `ps -aux` command to pushgateway, via curl :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

z=$(ps aux)
while read -r z
do
   var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\", cpu=\""$3"\"}", $3z}');
done <<< "$z"

curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "$var
" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

Everything's ok on this one, my crontab send every minute the formatted data to `localhost:9091`, my pushgateway instance.

Now, I'm trying to send a parsed result of the `service --status-all` command, with a script called `services_list.sh`, exactly the way I've dealed with the `cpu_usage.sh` script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

y=$(service --status-all)
while read -r y
do
   varx=$varx$(awk '{print "services_list{service=\""$y"\"}", 1}');
done <<< "$y"

curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "$varx
" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

When executing both scripts manually, like `./cpu_usage.sh` and `./services_list.sh`, everything's fine, Pushgateway is successfully retrieving data from both scripts.

But when I'm passing theses calls by CRON, only `cpu_usage.sh` is sending data to pushgateway (timestamp of last push on `services_list` method on Pushgateway stays unchanged).

My crontab syntax is like : `* * * * * cd /path/ && ./script.sh`

Scripts are in `777` / `root:root`, crontab is always edited as root. I've tried to concatenate both scipts in one bash file, and no matter the order I put them, the curl call for `services_list` method is never made (but everything's ok on `cpu_usage` method).

I'm a bit lost, as the two scripts are very similar, and manual calls on `services_list.sh` are working fine. Any thoughts ? Thank you.

Running on Debian 9 with Pushgateway 0.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fixed :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127433/unable-to-run-a-service-command-via-cron)

The command `service` is not callable from crontab. I have to furnish the full path of the `service` ressource when calling it from cron, like `/usr/sbin/service --options`.

In this context, everything's running fine with `y=$(/usr/sbin/service --status-all)` in place of `y=$(service --status-all)` in my `services_list.sh` script.